# Using `\State` inside `beamercolorbox` causes error Missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: beamer, algorithms, presentations, algorithmic

I have a `frame` in my `beamer` presentation. Inside a frame I have an `algorithmic` in a `minipage`. Inside that algorithmic I have the following to highlight an ares in the algorithm.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\begin{document}
    \maketitle

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \makebox[\textwidth]{
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
            content
        \end{minipage}
        \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{algorithmic}[]
            \Function{DivisibleOnce}{v, e}
            \newline
            \setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=white,bg=purple}
            \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.9 \textwidth,rounded=true,shadow=true]{postit}
                \State $ s $
            \end{beamercolorbox}
            \EndFunction
        \end{algorithmic}
        \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The above Latex causes Error at the end of the frame. The example works if I comment out `\State $ s $`

> Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{frame}

However If I use `\If` or `\Return` it works

Comment: Please do not post such fragments, but the document that contains this code. Perhaps you need `\begin{frame}[fragile]`

Comment: tried didn't work. added snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You should have the `beamercolorbox` environment after `\State`, not conversely.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \Function{DivisibleOnce}{v, e}
  \State
   $ s $
  \EndFunction
  \Function{DivisibleOnce}{v, e}
  \State
  \setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=white,bg=purple}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.9 \textwidth,rounded=true,shadow=true]{postit}
   $ s $
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But this breaks indentation in the output, before DivisibleOnce I have another function where I have `\If` inside `beamercolorbox` which is working fine. But If I put beamercolorbox after `\State` it indents more. And why it works with \If But not with \State ?